# Exclude predefined package in `environment.systemPackages`

Tags: nixos

There is a default list of system packages for Nixos:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/582313bafef4c81cb6df2dcf2ece4757eb5c8082/nixos/modules/config/system-path.nix

How can I exclude some of predefined packages from `environment.systemPackages` (for example, `texinfo`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NixOS module system does not currently support this. You *can* use `mkForce` to override all definitions of an option value at the default priority level, but that will get rid of all predefined packages, which is not what you want.